# Why am I getting SON::ParserError trying to validate response using json_matchers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, jsonserializer, jsonparser

**app/models/author.rb:**

```
                class Author < ApplicationRecord
                  validates :name, presence: true,
                                   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
                end
```

**app/serializers/author_serializer.rb:**

```
              class AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
                  attributes :id, :name, :bio
                end
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb:**

```
    #...

require 'json_matchers/rspec'
JsonMatchers.schema_root = 'spec/support/api/schemas.author.json':
 #...
```

**spec/support/api/schemas/authors/show.json:**

```
{
  "id": "file:/authors/show.json#",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "authors": {
      "description": "A collection of authors",
      "example": [{ "id": "1", "name": "Name" }],
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "file:/author.json#"
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["authors"],
  "properties": {
    "authors": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/authors"
    }
  }
}
```

**spec/requests/authors_show_request_pec.rb:**

```
    RSpec.describe 'Authors', type: :request do
      setup { host! 'api.example.com' }
    
      describe 'GET /author/:id' do
        let!(:author) { create(:author, id: 13, name: 'Name', bio: 'bio') }
        it 'returns requested author' do
          get author_path(13)
          expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
          author_from_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
          expect(author_from_response['name']).to eq(author.name)
          expect(author_from_response['bio']).to eq(author.bio)
          expect(response).to match_json_schema('author')
        end
  end
```

end

Response body contains all expected data, but spec if falinig to validate matching response to json schema.
Json_matchers gem seems to be configured according to manual.
Error that appears:

```
JsonMatchers::InvalidSchemaError:
       783: unexpected token at '}
       '
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the trailing commas. The ruby JSON parser does not like them.
Your JSON response should be:

```
{
  "id": "file:/authors/index.json#",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "authors": {
      "description": "A collection of authors",
      "example": [{ "id": "1", "name": "Name" }],
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "file:/author.json#"
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["authors"],
  "properties": {
    "authors": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/authors"
    }
  }
}
```

**Notice no trailing commas after the "items", "authors" nor "properties".**

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately this leads me to another error:JsonMatchers::InvalidSchemaError:
       783: unexpected token at '}
       '

Comment: still the problem was with the commas. Thank you very much for your help! The problem has been solved.